# Referring to a "std::unique_ptr" that you don't own (use a raw pointer?)

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, unique-ptr, weak-ptr

Typically if you are using a `std::shared_ptr` to point to an object and you want to create another pointer to that object that does not share ownership you would create a `std::weak_ptr`.

```
// Create a shared pointer to own the object
std::shared_ptr<int> p = std::make_shared<int>(42);

// Create a weak pointer (that does not own the object)
std::weak_ptr<int> q(p);

// Use the weak pointer some time later
if (std::shared_ptr ptr = q.lock()) {
  // use *ptr
}
```

My question is, how do you do this when it comes to `std::unique_ptr`?

Using a unique pointer ensures that the current resource is owned exclusively by the `std::unique_ptr` itself. But what if I want to create a pointer to the same resource that does not own that resource? I can't use a `std::weak_ptr` because weak pointers are designed to work with the reference count from a `std::shared_ptr`. Would I just use a raw pointer here? Or is there a better alternative?

```
// Create a unique pointer to own the object
std::unique_ptr<int> p = std::make_unique<int>(42);

// Create a non-owning pointer to the same object
// Is this really the best way?
int* q = p.get();

// Use the pointer some time later
if (q != nullptr) {

  // Imagine this may be multithreaded...
  // what happens if p.reset() is called by another thread while the current thread is RIGHT HERE.

  // use *q
}
```

The only way I can think of creating a non-owning pointer to an object owned by a `std::unique_ptr` would be to use a raw pointer, but as you can see from the code above this may cause issues in threaded applications. Is there a better way to achieve the same goal?

Comment: Yes, just use raw pointer, or, C++ Core Guidelines have some special type for non-owning pointer, which I can't remember from the top of my head.

Comment: It depends.  `weak_ptr` provides the semantics that it will extend the lifetime of the object while it is locked.  Do you want this in the `unique_ptr` case or are you okay with the object getting deleted while you are using it?

Comment: You can also use reference to `unique_ptr` but you have to be pretty sure that it will be alive the whole time when you want to use it.

Comment: @Qeek, in the particular case I am trying to use this, I am using the pointer to traverse through a data structure of `std::unique_ptr` objects. In order to traverse the structure, the pointer I create needs to be able to move what it is pointing to to reference the next unique pointer in the data structure... The issue is references are not reassignable so if I use a reference I can't change it to point to the next item in the data structure.

Comment: @SergeyA, what if it is a requirement for my application to be thread safe? Using a raw pointer could cause issues with multi threading.

Comment: @SergeyA it's `gsl::observer<T>`, and iirc it's an alias for `T*`

Comment: "Using a raw pointer could cause issues with multi threading". Using just about anything, smart pointers included, could cause issues with multi threading

Comment: I would use a *raw pointer* for both `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` unless the application demanded a `std::weak_ptr`. No point in paying for things you don't use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on your last example, this is a scenario where `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` should be used.

`std::unique_ptr` and a non-owning Raw Pointer should be used in the scenario where you have a guarantee that the smart pointer will outlive the raw pointer.

```
class A {
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr = std::make_unique<int>(5);
public:
    int* get_ptr() const{return ptr.get();}
};

class B {
    A a;
public:
    void do_something() {
        //int * ptr = a.get_ptr();//Valid, but not advised
        int & ref = *a.get_ptr();//Preferred
        ref++;
    }
};
```

If you can make this guarantee, you should be using `std::unique_ptr` and a raw pointer to represent this object. This is ideomatically correct.

If, however, you can't guarantee lifetime at the time you need to manipulate the object, then references should be provided by `std::weak_ptr`, which are used to acquire ownership (even if only temporarily!) to make changes.

```
class A {
    std::shared_ptr<int> ptr = std::make_shared<int>(5);
public:
    std::weak_ptr<int> get_ptr() const {
        return ptr;//Implicitly converts
    }
    void destroy() {
        ptr.reset();
    }
};

class B {
    std::weak_ptr<int> ptr;
public:
    B(std::weak_ptr<int> ptr) : ptr(ptr) {}
    void do_something() {
        if(auto owned_ptr = ptr.lock()) {//owned_ptr will be deduced to be of type std::shared_ptr<int>
            *owned_ptr++; //Guaranteed to only execute if the pointer is still valid
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b(a.get_ptr());
    if(get_random_value() > 10)
        a.destroy();
    b.do_something();
}
```

Comment: `//int * ptr = a.get_ptr();//Valid, but not advised
        int & ref = *a.get_ptr();//Preferred` Why?  Both cases do the exact same thing.  If the pointer gets deleted out from under you then you are left with a dangling reference which is just as bad as a dangling pointer.

Comment: @NathanOliver The point of that example is that `B` owns its own reference to `A`, and is thus able to manage the lifetime of the pointer. So there's no risk [in properly documented code that maintains its invariants] of the pointer going out of scope. So left with the choice of a reference or pointer with no concern for lifetime, prefer the reference.

Answer (score 7):

#### It depends on whether the extra pointer may outlive the `unique_ptr`.

- If the non-owning pointer **absolutely cannot outlive** the `unique_ptr`: Make it a plain pointer. Whoever gets this kind of pointer can assume it's valid, but cannot presume to own the memory it points to.
- If the non-owning pointer **might outlive** the `unique_ptr`: Your original pointer is not really "unique"; and you should replace the `unique_ptr` with a `shared_ptr` and pass a `weak_ptr` as the non-owning copy.

I just noticed that this answer is basically a brief summary of [Xirema's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55028735/1593077). Please upvote/accept that answer!